# How to compare numerical values in the same columns for multiple columns using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view that combines data from 3 tables that has this structure.

```
TABLE    PERIOD  COUNTRY  CODE  POSITION  OCT_14  NOV_14  DEC_14
TABLE_1  Q1      UK       123   EMPL      .2      .2      .2
TABLE_2  Q1      Uk       123   EMPL      .2      .2      .2
TABLE_3  Q1      UK       123   EMPL      .3      .4      .4
```

What I am trying to do is compare  the TABLE_3 rows to TABLE_1 and TABLE_2 for the OCT_14, NOV_14 AND DEC_14 columns.  If the numerical value for TABLE_3 is > than that of TABLE_1 or 2 I would like it to return some type of flag like 'Attention'.

In terms of desired output, I am ok with either have a new row with a unique name or a new column such as OCT_14_R.  Having a new row is actually preferred.

```
TABLE    PERIOD  COUNTRY  CODE  POSITION  OCT_14  OCT_14_R     NOV_14  DEC_14
TABLE_1  Q1      UK       123   EMPL      .2                    .2      .2
TABLE_2  Q1      Uk       123   EMPL      .2                    .2      .2
TABLE_3  Q1      UK       123   EMPL      .3       Attn         .4      .4
```

OR

```
TABLE    PERIOD  COUNTRY  CODE  POSITION  OCT_14  NOV_14  DEC_14
TABLE_1  Q1      UK       123   EMPL      .2      .2      .2
TABLE_2  Q1      Uk       123   EMPL      .2      .2      .2
TABLE_3  Q1      UK       123   EMPL      .3      .4      .4
Comparison                                 attn    attn    attn
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but for this kind of work, it is usually "best" to work at original table level, rather than on some more or less "artificial" view -- for which you will probably need self-join and/or self-subqueries anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create Table V(TName VARCHAR(5), Oct_14 NUMBER(5,2), Nov_14 NUMBER(5,2), Dec_14 NUMBER(5,2));

Insert into V values('T1', 1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
Insert into V values('T2', 1.4, 1.5, 1.6);
Insert into V values('T3', 1.5, 1.5, 1.7);

SELECT TName, To_Char(Oct_14) Oct_14, To_Char(Nov_14) Nov_14, To_Char(Dec_14) Dec_14 from V
UNION
SELECT 'Compare', 
(select 'ATTN' from dual where EXISTS (select 1 from V where TName = 'T3' and OCT_14 > ALL(SELECT OCT_14 FROM V WHERE TName IN ('T1','T2')))) Oct_14_Res,
(select 'ATTN' from dual where EXISTS (select 1 from V where TName = 'T3' and Nov_14 > ALL(SELECT Nov_14 FROM V WHERE TName IN ('T1','T2')))) Nov_14_Res,
(select 'ATTN' from dual where EXISTS (select 1 from V where TName = 'T3' and Dec_14 > ALL(SELECT Dec_14 FROM V WHERE TName IN ('T1','T2')))) Dec_14_Res
FROM dual;
```

There should other ways to do it better.

Comment: I like the out put of the query best. thanks for that.  I would still need, period, country, code and position in the out put and ordered by period, country, code and position.  Not sure how to add those as my result gets..query block has incorrect # of results columns

Comment: Still could use some advise as per my comment above..bit overall this is working.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions, for instance

```
SELECT a.*, 
CASE 
  WHEN (a.oct_14 <> MIN(a.oct_14) OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY "TABLE" 
  RANGE BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) THEN 'attn' END as oct_14_r
FROM your_view a;
```

I assume "table+code" unique (otherwise you need to change `PARTITION BY` ) and ..._14 columns are not nullable.
"oct_14_r" will have 'attn' value when current row column not equals to minimum value of 2 "previous" (sorted by "TABLE" field) rows.

Beware of possible performance issues - you're using view, and optimizer may generate a wrong execution plan queries that use window/analytical functions

Comment: Hi..thanks for this idea..I will give it a try.  the unique elements are actually, period, country, code and position so I assume I would just separate these with commas.  Thanks again