# Oracle SQL for Comparing numerical values in the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view that has this structure which is a combination of 3 tables for which I need to compare the values in each numerical column (OCT_14, NOV_14, ETC.).

```
TABLE    PERIOD  COUNTRY  CODE  POSITION  OCT_14  NOV_14  DEC_14
TABLE_1  Q1      UK       123   EMPL      .2      .2      .2
TABLE_2  Q1      Uk       123   EMPL      .2      .2      .2
TABLE_3  Q1      UK       123   EMPL      .3      .4      .4
```

I was provided the following code in a previous post but there are few things I need to clarify.

[How to compare numerical values in the same columns for multiple columns using Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065442/how-to-compare-numerical-values-in-the-same-columns-for-multiple-columns-using-o/26066176#26066176)

I need the additional fields (PERIOD, COUNTRY, CODE AND POSITION) in the query and each of these creates a unique ID.  The comparison would occur in a query that would return the compare row where (PERIOD, COUNTRY, CODE AND POSITION) are the same for each table.  Ultimately, the compare row would return like this..

```
TABLE    PERIOD  COUNTRY  CODE  POSITION  OCT_14  NOV_14  DEC_14
TABLE_1  Q1      UK       123   EMPL      .2      .2      .2
TABLE_2  Q1      Uk       123   EMPL      .2      .2      .2
TABLE_3  Q1      UK       123   EMPL      .3      .4      .4
COMPARE                                   ATTN     ATTN    ATTN
```

When I run this query I get nulls for the compare row using this query, not ATTN.  I believe it is because that unique element is missing.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

Here is the code in the previous post:

```
Create Table V(TName VARCHAR(5), Oct_14 NUMBER(5,2), Nov_14 NUMBER(5,2), Dec_14 NUMBER(5,2));

Insert into V values('T1', 1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
Insert into V values('T2', 1.4, 1.5, 1.6);
Insert into V values('T3', 1.5, 1.5, 1.7);

SELECT TName, To_Char(Oct_14) Oct_14, To_Char(Nov_14) Nov_14, To_Char(Dec_14) Dec_14 from V
UNION
SELECT 'Compare', 
(select 'ATTN' from dual where EXISTS (select 1 from V where TName = 'T3' and OCT_14 > ALL(SELECT
 OCT_14 FROM V WHERE TName IN ('T1','T2')))) Oct_14_Res,
(select 'ATTN' from dual where EXISTS (select 1 from V where TName = 'T3' and Nov_14 > ALL(SELECT
 Nov_14 FROM V WHERE TName IN ('T1','T2')))) Nov_14_Res,
(select 'ATTN' from dual where EXISTS (select 1 from V where TName = 'T3' and Dec_14 > ALL(SELECT
Dec_14 FROM V WHERE TName IN ('T1','T2')))) Dec_14_Res
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is SQL Fiddle demo : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1462f7/3

```
select "TABLE", "PERIOD", "COUNTRY", "CODE", "POSITION", to_char(Oct_14) Oct_14 , To_Char(Nov_14) Nov_14, To_Char(Dec_14) Dec_14  from Table1
union 
select 'COMPARE', '','', NULL, '',
(select 'ATTN' from dual where EXISTS (select 1 from Table1 where "TABLE" = 'TABLE_3' and OCT_14 > ALL(SELECT OCT_14 FROM Table1 WHERE "TABLE" IN ('TABLE_1','TABLE_2')))) Oct_14_Res,
(select 'ATTN' from dual where EXISTS (select 1 from Table1 where "TABLE" = 'TABLE_3' and Nov_14 > ALL(SELECT Nov_14 FROM Table1 WHERE "TABLE" IN ('TABLE_1','TABLE_2')))) Nov_14_Res,
(select 'ATTN' from dual where EXISTS (select 1 from Table1 where "TABLE" = 'TABLE_3' and Dec_14 > ALL(SELECT Dec_14 FROM Table1 WHERE "TABLE" IN ('TABLE_1','TABLE_2')))) Dec_14_Res
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Hi..thanks for this Rajesh.  In your SQL Fiddle demo all of the values that are pulled back form the query are 0.00 so it does not look like there is any comparison.  Any idea why, because the table has values for OCT, NOV and DEC 2014?  Thanks,

Comment: This works great..!  Thanks :)  If I need to limit the data using a where statement where would it go?

Comment: i modified it, text to ddl converted value to numeric istead of decimal.

Comment: @Ewaver, you need to add where clause in the first select and also  in the subquery TCount where counts are calculated, accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Hi..it is very close.  The comparison is if the table1 value is > the table 2 or 3 within the numerical columns.  The query returns Attn no matter what.

Comment: AFter looking at this it does not compare the data in the columns like I need.  Table1 needs to be compared to Tables 2 and 3 within each Oct_14, Nov_14, etc column.  If the OCT_14 value is .3 (as above) and is > Tables 2 and 3 values then it would give Attn.  Have any other ideas?  Really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62364/discussion-between-ewaver-and-rajesh).